# Apache Camel AS2 component cannot not process application/xml message

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I tested to send a message with content-type set to application/xml to a Camel/AS2 server connection. However, I got 500 response. Does Camel/AS2 support application/xml content-typed messages?

### Here comes the stack trace:

2022-01-16 11:44:23,725 [AS2Hdlr-6405] INFO  .AS2ServerConnection [] - Processing new AS2 request
2022-01-16 11:44:23,725 [AS2Hdlr-6405] WARN  nent.as2.AS2Consumer [] - Failed to process AS2 message
org.apache.http.HttpException: Failed to extract EDI message: invalid content type 'application/xml' for AS2 request message
at org.apache.camel.component.as2.api.util.HttpMessageUtils.extractEdiPayload(HttpMessageUtils.java:169) ~[camel-as2-api-3.13.0.jar!/:3.13.0]
at org.apache.camel.component.as2.AS2Consumer.handle(AS2Consumer.java:124) [camel-as2-3.13.0.jar!/:3.13.0]
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService.doService(HttpService.java:437) [wildfly-elytron-1.18.1.Final.jar!/:1.18.1.Final]
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService.handleRequest(HttpService.java:342) [wildfly-elytron-1.18.1.Final.jar!/:1.18.1.Final]
at org.apache.camel.component.as2.api.AS2ServerConnection$RequestHandlerThread.run(AS2ServerConnection.java:147) [camel-as2-api-3.13.0.jar!/:3.13.0]
2022-01-16 11:44:23,725 [AS2Hdlr-6405] INFO  .AS2ServerConnection [] - Client closed connection

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the consumer that generated the 500 response?

Comment: I just posted the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks, and I wish I could give you an answer.  But " invalid content type 'application/xml'" in your trace says it all.  It looks like the AS2 Camel component only supports the EDI formats, specifically the ones they list in their documentation: application/edifact, application/edi-x12, application/edi-consent.